# Mercurial integration into Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, mercurial

Is there a way of integrating Mercurial into Visual Studio 2005? We'd like to be able to do checkin's, see history, etc. directly from the IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A hyperlink is worth a thousand words ;-)

http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html

Comment: Thanks. The suggested plugin is actually for visual studio 2008, so I'm assuming there are no solutions for 2005.

Comment: Further down on the page it states "First release of Mercurial SCC plugin for MS Visual Studio 2005/2008."

Did you try that version?

Answer (score 5):

[VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) which in turn needs [TortoiseHG](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home)