# Which DVCS for a one-man .NET shop?

Tags: .net, windows, dvcs

I'm the only developer working in a very small company. I currently use VisualSVN on Windows on my development machine as my VCS.  This is problematic because I can't get to my projects outside the IT firewall, and my colleague can't integrate his content into my projects.

We (my PM, who develops content for me) are very interested in a hosted DVCS.  My rough requirements would be:

- Projects can be accessed from anywhere with an internet connection
- Projects can be protected
- Cost is cheap-or-free

What sort of services do you think would fit?

Comment: Many dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496423/git-versus-mercurial-for-net-developers

Comment: Possible dupes were 4+ months old and almost always focused on git vs Mercurial.  I feel like my scope is different enough to warrant a new question.

Comment: Surprisingly, everyone feels that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use and love [Codespaces.com](http://www.codespaces.com/).  It's cheap and comes with a great project management dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all DVCSs have some hosted services available that provide the features you are asking for:

- [Git](http://Git-SCM.Com/) has [GitHub](https://GitHub.Com/), [Unfuddle](http://Unfuddle.Com/), [Assembla](https://Assembla.Com/), [Codebase](http://CodebaseHQ.Com/), [ProjectLocker](https://ProjectLocker.Com/)
- [Mercurial](http://Mercurial.Selenic.Com/) has [BitBucket](https://BitBucket.Org/)
- [darcs](http://Darcs.Net/) has [Patch-Tag](https://Patch-Tag.Com/)